# How to spy (using Jest) on the child component method in enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component CustomerAccountDetails which is wrapped inside a Provider component.
I am spying on the method 'fetchAccountDetails' inside component CustomerAccountDetails for accountId that I have provided

Following is the code of the component CustomerAccountDetails:

```
class CustomerAccountDetails extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      if(this.props.accountId) {
        this.props.fetchAccountDetails(this.props.accountId);
      }
    } 

    render() {
       return <AccountDetails details={this.props.accountDetails}/>
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators(
    {
     fetchAccountDetails: accountId => getAccountDetails(accountId) 
    },
    dispatch
  );

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    accountDetails: state.accountDetails    
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CustomerAccountDetails);
```

Following is the sample code snippet of enzyme:

```
it('should fetch account details for the account id provided', () => {
    const spyOn = jest.spyOn(
      CustomerAccountDetails.prototype,
      'fetchAccountDetails'
    );
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <CustomerAccountDetails accountId="1234" />
      </Provider>
    );
    expect(spyOn).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

But when I run this above test case, it is showing the error as "Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given".

How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the Inversion of Control principle and pass the function as a prop for the component.

It will be easier to test and will make your component more reusable.

```
it('should fetch account details for the account id provided', () => {
    const fetchAccountDetailsMock = jest.fn();

    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <CustomerAccountDetails 
            accountId="1234" 
            fetchAccountDetails={fetchAccountDetailsMock} // now you have control over it
        />
      </Provider>
    );

    expect(fetchAccountDetailsMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: Hi Arnaud Claudel,  thanks for the answer but what to do when my method fetchAccountDetails is mapped to redux action, in that case it is not working.

Comment: Hi Arnaud Claudel, I have added the code of the component, please ignore my test case which is old one, I made changes in component comparing with your test case which is not working.